# Members parse into undefined instead of default value, if they missed in JSON string

Tags: json, angular

It's really expensive to transfer whole model from server to client specially when loading lists. The solution is to ignore empty, null or default values which can be refilled in client side. Consider a `Customer` model like this:

```
export class Customer {
    customerId: number = 0;
    ncode: string = 'some default text';
    name: string = '';
    age: int = 20;
    isActive: boolean = false;
    birthday: Date | null = null;

    // And much more fields ...
}
```

We have same model in server side and the server will ignore null and default fields in serialization. For example, this is a customer sent from server:

```
"{'customerId':1234}"
```

What happens is that the object created by angular http get, is a `Customer` with only `customerId` field! All other fields are undefined.
Is there any solution to fix it globally with no third party library to force angular to value missing fields with their default values?

Update:
Here is the request code:

```
export class CustomerComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.http.get<Customer>('/api/getCustomer').subscribe((response) => {
      console.log(response); // {'customerId':12345}
    });
  }
}
```

Update 2:
As I thought there may be a global solution, I made a simple example. But we have a generic function to handle all api requests, which is generic and returns `<T>(<any>response)`

```
public request<T>(api: string, method: string = 'GET', formData: any): Observable<T>{
    return new Observable((observer: Observer<T>) => {
        header = new HttpHeaders({/*...*/});
        this.http.request<T>(new HttpRequest(method, api, JSON.stringify(formData), {headers: header}))
            .subscribe({next: (response) => {
                observer.next(<T>(<any>response)); // <= This line must be changed I think
            }});
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share your http request code

Comment: Question updated @MehyarSawas

Comment: Did you tried to make fields as optional field like birthday?: Date | null;

Comment: @AmalSR I do not want to make it optional, as they are not! The only reason they are removed from request is that they have their default values

Comment: @Arash Ghasemi Rad: Can you please include your generic function that handles all api requests? Maybe it will help us finding a more generic solution.

Comment: It's really huge but ok, I'll share the main parts. I'm updating the question

Comment: The difficulty is that you cannot instantiate T easily. I created a solution where you would have to call `this.httpGet<Customer>('/api/getCustomer', Customer)` but of course this is not a 100% perfect solution because you have to pass the object-type as a separate parameter. Would you still be interested in this solution?

Comment: @kellermat I just learned new things from your solution and I'm really appreciate that. But I'm looking for a solution for my project and of course other users in the future. Other users can also use your current solution as well

Answer (score 4):

When you receive the data from the backend you could do the following trick:

1. Instantiate a new object of the desired class: It will automatically contain your default-values.
2. Merge the newly created object with the incoming data, using the spread-operator.

```
ngOnInit(): void {      
    this.http.get<Customer>('/api/getCustomer').pipe(
        // Instantiate an object with default-values
        // and merge it with the retrieved partial-object:
        map(res =>({ ...new Customer(), ...res } as Customer))
    )
    .subscribe((response) => { console.log(response); });
}
```

Comment: What if I want to make my http request generic in a service? I mean, for example, returning `<T>(<any>response)` is now works. How should I change it?

Answer (score 0):

**Explained**

Using Customer class as type for the http request does not influence the runtime code. Http resonse will not automatically create a new instance of your Customer class and assign the values to it. Types in typescript are just used for development purpose (compiler time) and will not influence the runtime code results. Checkout [w3school](https://www.w3schools.com/typescript/typescript_intro.php) introduction.

> TypeScript uses compile time type checking. Which means it checks if the specified types match before running the code, not while running the code.

**Solution**

To get a Customer with your defaults you could create a new instance of the Customer    which has the static default you have defined and assign only the http resonse values that are set. Something like :

```
      this.request<Customer>('/api/getCustomer').subscribe((response) => {
        const customer = new Customer();
     
        Object.keys(response).forEach(field => {
             
                   customer[field] = response[field];
              
          });
          
          console.log(customer); // response will be a Customer instance 
        });
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but please read the question completely, as I said I need generic function.

Comment: Yes I see. This will work too. http.get was also generic. Now that you have your own request method you can still use the same solution but calling request instead of http.get. I updated my answer